# How can I access a class from a external maven dependency in GWT?

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am reading a project of gwt and maven. I have a maven project of server side implementation which contain all method of DML opretion. now this project is use in a maven-gwt project as a dependency. and in a RPC call of server side they directly creating the instance of side implementation to communicate with database. but as per the gwt conviction it should reside in server side. so how this is working

**My server Implementation in maven**

```
  ModuleImp
     src 
       imp1.java
       imp2.java
       imp3.java
```

**My GWT maven project**

```
   GWTparent
       client
       shared
       server
```

please help....Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you mean development mode or production mode? Which one is not working? Client side or server side? What exactly do you mean with "I am still not able use this class on server as well as client"? Is it a compile time error or runtime error? Show us the complete error message or stack trace. If you want to use the DTO classes also in client code,  then these classes should reside in a `client` package. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @nitin verma: Instead of adding this explanation in a comment, please be suggested to add them on the question itself - People might lose track of comments for clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GWT` complier only cares about code in client and shared package(defined in `*.gwt.xml under source tag`). It ignores everything used and referred in server packages. In fact you can create a separate maven module for your server layer as well by adding appropriate dependencies to your GWT webapp